# How do you inspect events bound with .on() with jQuery 1.7+?

Tags: jquery

The old version of doing this doesn't seem to work..

```
$(".object").data('events');
```

..when I bind with this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".object", awesomePossumFunction() );
```

This does not show the events :

```
$(".object").data('events');
```

Comment: You're binding the event to the `document`, not the `.object` element, so the event will be available if you check the `document`, which is the element that has the event bound!

Comment: Does `awesomePossumFunction` return a function, or is that a typo? You might not want to call it.

Comment: Well its a replacement for an actual function that I use, so yes. ;). Events are most certainly bound to the handler because the objects respond to them. There's just no way to identify them via jQuery with 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just fine if you check for events on the actual element it was bound to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".object", awesomePossumFunction); //binds to document

var events  = $.data(document, 'events');  //jQuery 1.7.2 and below
var events2 = $._data(document, 'events'); //jQuery 1.8 ++
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwv69/)

Comment: Interesting, if I do $(".object").on("click", awesomePossumFunction() );, then I can not do the $._data($(".object"), 'events'); ..

Comment: @Trip - you can if you do `$._data($(".object")[0], 'events')`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not use .data('events'), it has been removed from newer versions of jQuery. You can access it at it's new location in newer versions of jQuery, but that also isn't suggested as it is subject to change.

Reference: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589

The important bits from that ticket is that in 1.7, changes to the event object were made that caused code that used `.data('events')` to not function properly. The new location is `jQuery._data(elem, "events")`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PxFx/

Comment: I believe it was added in 1.8, so it won't be available in 1.7. In 1.7 you're stuck with the buggy `.data('events')`

Comment: Correct. In their (the jquery team) defense, it is undocumented, and therefore subject to change. **;)**

Comment: Yikes! Just realized I'm using 1.8 :(

Comment: I think it was mentioned in the ticket that it was going to be added to an extension later. *"Summary changed from Deprecate $.fn.data("events") - Replace with debugging extension to Remove $.fn.data("events")
Per the blog entry:  http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/"*

Answer (score 0):

Your second line is something I never used. The handler might not be registered where you want it to.
I would do this instead:

```
$(".object").on("click", awesomePossumFunction());
```

Let me know if this was of any good.

Comment: Basically with `.on`, you can find to a parent object so that the DOM doesn't get refreshed from the bottom up, but can be traced back from your parent selector instead.. consequentialyl saving yourself a little time.

Comment: Actually, using a delegated event with the document as base won't save you any time, quite the opposite, and calling the function with the parenthesis will, wait for it, call the function immedieately!

Comment: You missed my point: what I meant that while binding the way you do, jquery might use event delegation and in that case your event is not going to be bound to your class. I will look into this, because I am not sure about it, I would just do it like this.

Comment: And yes, I was right: use this and you will that it was bound to the document and not to the $(".object"): jQuery._data(document, 'events'); -- but as I see, you already got a good answer, I was late.